# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

Have not worked with ASP in a very long time and have never dealt with stored procedures. I am sure this is grade 1 stuff.

Help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Have a stored procedure in MYSQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_custdetails`(IN p_Email VARCHAR(100), 
IN p_Fname VARCHAR(50), IN p_Lname VARCHAR(50), 
IN p_IP VARCHAR(40), IN p_OS VARCHAR(10), 
IN p_Browser VARCHAR(20), 
OUT ID INTEGER(11))
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
  `customerdetails`(
  Email,
  Fname,
  Lname,
  IP,
  OS,
  Browser)
VALUES(
  p_Email,
  p_Fname,
  p_Lname,
  p_IP,
  p_OS,
  p_Browser);


Set ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

END;
```

Then My Code in ASP:

```
SQL="CALL insert_custdetails ('1'," & _
    "'2'," & _
    "'3'," & _
    "'4'," & _
    "'5'," & _
    "'6');"
If Database(SQL) Then
    Response.Write Rs("ID")
End IfError is:
```

The Result

```
-2147467259: 
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.34-community]Incorrect 
number of arguments for PROCEDURE mytable.insert_custdetails; 
expected 7, got 6
```

What exactly do I need to do to declare that 7th parameter? How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

You should be using a SQLCommand and parameter properties.  The link shows example.